# How can I prevent navigation back using CEFSharp library?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I want to prevent navigation back for my application using CEFSharp library and WinForms. I have found no solutions for this, only some links here:
[How to disable backspace "go back" navigation?](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/608) but it`s not work for me.
Do you help me?

--> RequestHandler.cs

```
class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{
    public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isRedirect, bool isMainFrame)
    {
        if ((request.TransitionType & TransitionType.ForwardBack) != 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
    {

    }

    public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isMainFrame)
    {
        return CefReturnValue.Continue;
    }

    public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme,
        ref string username, ref string password)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnBeforePluginLoad(IWebBrowser browser, string url, string policyUrl, WebPluginInfo info)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
    {

    }
}
```

--> In Program.cs

```
_browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url)
        {
            RequestHandler = new RequestHandler(),
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            RequestHandler = new RequestHandler()
        };
```

P.S. the application I launched in the browser is single page.

Comment: What version are you using? What does the code you've tried look like?

Comment: Version is 41.0.1
I am trying to use OnBeforeBrowse method of the RequestHandler class as suggested in the link but it is invoked just one time when the application starts and is not invoked when I use Backspace in the app

Comment: https://github.com/amaitland/CefSharp.MinimalExample/commit/64cdadeacadf60b396d1d46182c5fd8e1fa931a1 works for me when using google to navigate to a website then pressing backspace. If it doesn't work for you, then can you provide a `jsfiddle` to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually if you can branch `MinimalExample` to demo your problem that would be even better. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: I replace OnBeforeBrowse by implementation but back button still work.
Should I add 
browser.NavStateChanged += OnBrowserNavStateChanged;
or it is not obligatory?

Comment: Are you talking for demo purposes? No need to worry about the back button or anything else, just demo the problem at hand.

Comment: amaitland, I use RequestHandler implementation like in Demo, but backspace still work. I have used the breakpoints and seen that OnBeforeBrowse method invoke only one time when the app loads.

Comment: I have tried to open google.com page and observe that your suggestion works perfect if a page replace the uri like HTML5 but if in the page change only hash (for me it is important because we use angular with no-HTML5 urls) you can use backspace without problems.

Comment: Just try to block navigation for this web page: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$animate/nocb
You see that navigation between right menu can not be blocked by your implementation.

Comment: Try asking on http://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php, I'm not aware of a method that suites your scenario. `CefSharp` is just a wrapper around `CEF`